# How to dynamically generate a list of classes with commas separating them?

Tags: css, sass

I'm working with the SCSS syntax of SASS to create a dynamic grid system but I've hit a snag.

I'm trying to make the grid system completely dynamic like this:

```
$columns: 12;
```

then I create the columns like this:

```
@mixin col-x {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .col-#{$i} { width: $column-size * $i; }
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.col-1 {
    width: 4.16667%;
  }

.col-2 {
    width: 8.33333%;
}
etc...
```

This works well but **what I want to do next is dynamically generate a long list of column classes separated by commas based on the number of $columns chosen** - e.g I want it to look like this:

```
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4,
 etc... {
float: left;
}
```

I've tired this:

```
@mixin col-x-list {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns - 1 {
  .col-#{$i}-m { float: left; }
  }
}
```

but the output is this:

```
.col-1 {
  float: left;
}
.col-2 {
  float: left;
}
etc...
```

I'm a little stuck on the logic here as well as the SCSS syntax required to create something like this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity: 
"@mixin col-x {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
  .col-#{$i} { width: $column-size * $i; }
  }
}" can you explain what this code do exactly?

Comment: @Mag It loops through the number of columns I set e.g. $columns: 6; and creates a class called col-1, col-2 etc. So if I want 6 columns it only cycles up to col-6. It then gives each col- a width of (100% divided by number of $columns then multiplied by it's column number) e.g. col-3 = (100% / 6) * 3 = 50%.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

I think you may want to take a look at `@extend`. If you set that up something like:

```
$columns: 12;

%float-styles {
  float: left;
}

@mixin col-x-list {
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
      .col-#{$i}-m { @extend %float-styles; }
  }
}

@include col-x-list;
```

It should render in your css file as:

```
.col-1-m, .col-2-m, .col-3-m, .col-4-m, .col-5-m, .col-6-m, .col-7-m, .col-8-m, .col-9-m, .col-10-m, .col-11-m, .col-12-m {
  float: left;
}
```

[@extend in the docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

Comment: Great. Your answer also describes how to create custom code like `.col-#{$i}-m`.

Answer (score 29):

There's also a way to do what your question is specifically asking for: *generate (and use) a list of classes with commas separating them.* D.Alexander's response totally works in your situation, but I'm posting this alternative in case there's another use case for someone looking at this question.

Here's a Pen demonstrating: http://codepen.io/davidtheclark/pen/cvrxq

Basically, you can use [Sass functions](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html) to achieve what you want. Specifically, I'm using `append` to add classes to my list, separated by commas, and `unquote` to avoid compilation conflicts with the period in the classnames.

So my mixin ends up looking like this:

```scss
@mixin col-x {
  $col-list: null;
  @for $i from 1 through $columns {
    .col-#{$i} {
      width: $column-size * $i;
    }
   $col-list: append($col-list, unquote(".col-#{$i}"), comma);
  }
  #{$col-list} {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

thnx to @davidtheclark here is a more generic version:

```
@mixin attr-x($attr, $attr-count: 10, $attr-steps: 10, $unit: '%') {
    $attr-list: null;
    @for $i from 1 through $attr-count {
        $attr-value: $attr-steps * $i;

        .#{$attr}#{$attr-value} {
            #{$attr}: #{$attr-value}#{$unit};
        }

        $attr-list: append($attr-list, unquote(".#{$attr}-#{$attr-value}"), comma);
    }

    #{$attr-list} {
        //append style to all classes
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
@include attr-x('margin-left', 6, 5, 'px');
//or
@include attr-x('width');
```

The result looks like this:

```
.margin-left5 {
  margin-left: 5px; }

.margin-left10 {
  margin-left: 10px; }

...

.margin-left30 {
  margin-left: 30px; }

//or

.width10 {
  width: 10%; }

.width20 {
  width: 20%; }

...

.width100 {
  width: 100%; }
```