# Change default font in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I can't figure out how to change the default font in vuetify. I've been looking for the right variable within ./node_modules/vuetify, but I can't locate it.

I'd ideally not make any changes in the module, but would rather override such variables from outside the module.

Comment: Commenting on my own question 4.5 years later: I'm surprised by how active this question still is, continuing to receive upvotes and answers. I'm glad my question helps people out, but I'm perplexed why this is not addressed in a prominent place in vuetify's documentation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply set the font-family on `body`. If you are using webpack and importing the Vuetify stylus entry, `main.styl`, you can simply overwrite the `$font-family` variable with whatever font you want.

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. I found the name of the variable I needed to override is `$body-font-family`.

Comment: Truly wonderful work with vuetify, by the way. I'm loving how easily and quickly I can get an attractive and functional user interface up and running. Using pug/jade makes it even more fun. I've started to support on Patreon as well. Hope it continues to get better.

Comment: All available variables that can be changed can be found here: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl

Comment: Just to update @adelriosantiago 's link, it's https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_variables.styl as of November 2018

Comment: I found this article to be helpful too which is based on similar idea: https://medium.com/@jacobedawson/vuetify-vue-cli-3-change-default-font-a70c22adc55

Comment: Just to update @sab 's link it's https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss

Answer (score 49):

**Best way**

Define (if you use google fonts)

```scss
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Oxygen:300,400,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Comfortaa&display=swap');

$body-font-family: 'Oxygen';
$title-font: 'Comfortaa';
```

For `vuetify 2+`

```css
.v-application {
   font-family: $body-font-family, sans-serif !important;
   .title { # To pin point specific classes of some components
       font-family: $title-font, sans-serif !important;
   }
}
```

In app.vue or a separate scss/css file imported directly into app.vue

For `vuetify 1.5.x`
In your app.vue script add

```css
.application {
  font-family: "Font Family Name";
}
.headline,
.title,
.subheading{
    font-family: $body-font-family !important;
}
```

For example, if you are using a google font, your script tag should look like

```html
<style lang="scss">
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial");
    
.application {
  font-family: "Questrial";
}
</style>
```

### Update 2021

In your `main.scss` file,

```scss
$font-family:'Ubuntu';

.v-application {
  [class*='text-'] {
    color: #36405a;
    font-family: $font-family, sans-serif !important;
  }
  font-family: $font-family, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: I am using vuetify 2.x, i used recommended method, does not work on `.headline`?

Comment: That's because those classes often have a different font defined (A display font which will make it look a bit different). I have updated the answer to reference them as well.

Comment: @RaviAnand `.headline` was deprecated in 2.x

Comment: It works great until you specify class="text-h4" (or any other header number) to any element.

Comment: Lol, that is just the point this answer fixes @yaya ..

For vuetify 3 try adding `.v-application,
.v-overlay-container` instead of `.v-application` to be sure to cover the menu's that are teleported to the body 

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me using Nuxt.js with [Vuetify Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module) was simply setting the body font in variables.scss, like this:

`$body-font-family: SofiaPro, Roboto;`

All other fonts are derived from this one.

Default variables file ('~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass') is imported automatically afterwards and ignores a variable if it was already set (thanks to !default). Therefore there's no need to change $heading-font-family and individual $headings anymore.

For this to work with Nuxt module, do not forget to set treeShake: true in nuxt.config.js file. If you are not using Nuxt.js, then probably you need to import the variables file *after* setting the body font.

Here's an example of my nuxt.config.js file fragment:

```
buildModules: [
  '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
],

vuetify: {
  treeShake: true,
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  ... other Vuetify options
}
```

Where viariables.scss contains the above font definition.

I wrote a short article explaining this subject, containing a complete code example: https://medium.com/@jareklipski/changing-default-font-in-vuetify-js-and-nuxt-js-3894e726ff10

Comment: I tried, but nothing came of it. Is there an example of nuxt.confing? I am using the latest @nuxtjs/vuetify

Comment: @PavelLevin I updated the description adding a relevant nuxt.config.js fragment. Let me know if it works for you and if not, please share your configuration.

Comment: When adding `@nuxtjs/style-resources`, `node-sass` and `sass-loader`, `treeShake` stops working. This is strange. https://github.com/pl-ekleft/nuxt-vuetify-font

Comment: Strange. Unfortunately I can't help you since I am not using these particular libraries. I suggest to debug, reach out to their authors or to Vuetify author.

Comment: Problem in `node-sass` and `sass-loader`. Conflicts with vuetify. This is already in the nuxt :)

Answer (score 13):

I have noticed that, at least in recent versions of Vuetify, you need to specify both `$body-font-family` and `$heading-font-family` to change the fonts of everything from Roboto to something else in your overrides (following [these instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme#stylus-guide)). The redefinition of `$headings` seems to be necessary since it is defined in `_variables.styl` and depends on `$heading-font-family`. Note that Vuetify will be [moving to SCSS](https://www.patreon.com/posts/september-2018-21931872) in 2.0 so there will be a new process at that point.

```
$body-font-family = 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif
$heading-font-family = 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif
$headings = {
  h1: { size: 112px, weight: 300, line-height: 1, letter-spacing: -.04em, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  h2: { size: 56px, weight: 400, line-height: 1.35, letter-spacing: -.02em, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  h3: { size: 45px, weight: 400, line-height: 48px, letter-spacing: normal, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  h4: { size: 34px, weight: 400, line-height: 40px, letter-spacing: normal, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  h5: { size: 24px, weight: 400, line-height: 32px, letter-spacing: normal, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  h6: { size: 20px, weight: 500, line-height: 1, letter-spacing: .02em, font-family: $heading-font-family },
  subheading: { size: 16px, weight: 400 },
  body-2: { size: 14px, weight: 500 },
  body-1: { size: 14px, weight: 400 },
  caption: { size: 12px, weight: 400 },
  button: { size: 14px, weight: 500 }
}
```

Comment: I want to have a different font for headings. I've done what you recommend, but no matter what I try, it doesn't seem to want to override `$heading-font-family`. All of my headings still have whatever font is set for `$body-font-family`.

Comment: **Figured it out.** Oddly, the `font-family` is not applied to `h*` elements unless you apply one of the [heading classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/typography), e.g. `.headline` or `.display-1`. This is not intuitive.

Answer (score 13):

So vuetify provides a very simple solution.

In your src directory create a `sass`, `scss`, or `styles` directory and then create a file named `variables.scss` or `variables.sass` in it.

> When you run yarn serve or npm run serve, vuetify will automatically
> hoist the global Vuetify variables to all of your sass/scss files.

Example - `src/scss/variables.scss`

**Below code will change the default body font**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');
$body-font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
```

You can change a lot more stuff in there and can change webpack settings if above doesn't work for you directly - [check this link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/#sass-variables)

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should not import font in the **variables.scss** file. Because if you import the font in **variables.scss** file it will import every time on the time of compilation and the system will get very slow. Instead of importing it in the **variables.scss** file you just simply import the font in index.html file and add this part `$body-font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;` in the **variables.scss** file.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot guarantee that this is "best practice". But considering that there is no documentation on how to do this properly I am going to tell you how I accomplished this.

I am using the Nuxt webpack template so my file structure may be a bit different than yours but the concept is the same.

I have a static assets folder. Within that folder I have a global css file. I downloaded the font I was using as a file and added it to my static directory as well. But you could put it pretty much anywhere.

Here is the code that I added to my global CSS file:

```
@font-face{
            font-family: **any name you want to give the font**;
            src: url(**location in directory**) format("opentype");
            }
```

Then you just add it to you styling rules as you normally would

```
    *{
    font-family: **the same name you gave it above**;
 }
   h1{
    font-family: **the same name you gave it above**;
 }
```

ect...

Remember to enter the correct format. If your file downloads as a .otf it is opentype. If it is .ttf it is truetype.

I have not yet figured out how to include a font from CDN. If I do figure that out I will let you know.

Comment: This is how I first solved it (I'm also using Nuxt). But I've now instead overridden the `$body-font-family` variable in the main.styl file.

Comment: You can use a font from CDN in the exact same way. Just point your `src: url()` to the font's CDN location. See here: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Racing+Sans+One

Answer (score 3):

For Laravel Vuetify users, this all you need:
Update your webpack.min.js file to look like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/main.scss', 'public/css')
   .stylus('resources/stylus/main.styl', 'public/css');
```

Your `main.styl` should be located in the path: `resources\stylus\main.styl` 
 Your `main.styl` file should look like this:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Literata:400,500,600,700&display=swap");

$body-font-family = 'Literata', serif
$alert-font-size = 18px

@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
// For a-la-carte
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/app'
```

To prevent Vuetify from writing inline styles that could override your `main.css`, do:

```
 mix.options({
      extractVueStyles: true, // Extract .vue component styling to file, rather than inline.
      });
```

And finally, ensure stylus-loader is setup already, if not run in command line:

```
$ yarn add stylus stylus-loader style-loader css-loader -D
// OR
$ npm i stylus stylus-loader style-loader css-loader --save-dev
```

You can also npm install material-design-icons-iconfont.

```
npm install material-design-icons-iconfont --save
```

Answer (score 3):

This solution work on Vue-CLI>=3

First of all you must install sass-loader

```
npm install sass sass-loader fibers deepmerge -D
```

You should first create "sass" folder in the "src" directory, then
create a "variables.scss" file in this directory.

Then write the below code in this file.

```
$ body-font-family: Your-FontName
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss';
```

You need to restart your project now.

Answer (score 3):

Install your font via CDN/npm. Then just override this variable by adding this line in **./src/styles/variables.scss**

```
//Change default font to 'Inter'
$body-font-family: "Inter" !important;
```

A short and simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

For **vue 3** with **vite** and **vuetify 3.0.6** generated by `yarn create vuetify`

based on @arora answer and [official docs](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#sass-variables)

1. Run `npm install -D sass`
2. In `src/plugins/vuetify.js` replace `import 'vuetify/styles` with `import '../assets/main.scss'` as stated [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#basic-usage)
3. Create `main.scss` file in assets folder as stated

```
@use 'vuetify' with (
  $utilities: false,
  $color-pack: false,
  $body-font-family: 'Assistant'
 );
```

4. I had to set `utilities: yes` to resolve some style issues **(Do not use `true`)**.

Comment: also had to use "utililties: yes", otherwise everything was breaking on the page. Thanks for the info on how to do it properly

Comment: This is the best answer for vuetify 3. You do not need to add $utilities and $color-pack options though, they are unrelated and should only be changed if you want to disable that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Vuetify 2+, the process will be very similar to jeffbaumes's answer but using Sass instead of Stylus

```
// src/sass/main.scss
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

$body-font-family: 'My Custom Font', cursive;

$heading-font-family: $body-font-family, cursive;

@each $heading, $style in $headings {
    $headings: map-merge($headings, ($heading: map-merge($style, ('font-family': $heading-font-family))));
}
```

Or you can change the fonts of some heading styles and not others like this:

`$headings: map-merge($headings, ('h3': ('font-family': 'Custom Font Name')));`

Comment: not working for me  =(
@each $heading, $style in $headings {
                         ^
      Undefined variable.

Comment: Make sure to import the original Vuetify sass file at the top of src/sass/main.scss, like this: 

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, @alice-mx answer didn't work for me (couldn't import from node_modules).

This is how I solved this problem in my code (using **Vuetify 2**):

---

After downloading the wanted .woff2 file and put it in src/assets/fonts,
I added this code to my App.vue file (or whichever main vue file you set in your project):

```css
// App.vue
<style>
$typoOptions: display-4 display-3 display-2 display-1 headline title subtitle-1 subtitle-2 body-1 body-2 caption overline; // all md typography options provided by vuetify

%font-choice {
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif !important;
}

@mixin md-typography {
@each $typoOption in $typoOptions {
  .#{$typoOption} {
    @extend %font-choice;
  }
}

.v-application { // This is where we'll add all the md-typography classes
  font-size: 12px;
  @extend %font-choice;
  @include md-typography;
}

// add font-face because in this case Noto-Sans is taken from Google fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: "Noto Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Noto Sans"), local("NotoSans"),
    url("~@/assets/fonts/noto-sans-v9-latin-regular.woff2") format("woff2");
}
</style>
```

I hope this will help!

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19088399/5762431) helped me to form the .scss code

Comment: '@Tzahi Leh' i have followed your suggestion, but i see partially changed custom fonts. Can you please help me what am i missing? I have created a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57793387/2723677).

Comment: @mmar, did you find a solution?

Comment: '@Tzahi Leh' No, i couldn't. Still i see partially changed theme.

Answer (score 2):

My solution in (latest) Nuxt:

nuxt.config:

```
head: {
.......
link: [
  {rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico'},
  {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href:'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400|Roboto+Slab:200&display=swap'
  }
]
},

vuetify: {
treeShake: true,
customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],

theme: {
  .....
  },
}
},
```

variables.scss

```
$body-font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: Roboto Slab, serif;

@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything nothing was working in my case, but the below solution will definitely work though not the best solution

### Add the below scss in your variables.scss

```
$body-font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;

.v-application {
  .text-h1,
  .text-h2,
  .text-h3,
  .text-h4,
  .text-h5,
  .text-h6,
  .text-headline,
  .text-title,
  .text-subtitle-1,
  .text-subtitle-2,
  .text-body-1,
  .text-body-2,
  .text-button,
  .text-caption,
  .text-overline {
    font-family: $body-font-family !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using webpack and the only way I could make it work was:

**// webpack.config.js**

```
...
{
  test: /\.sass$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      // Vuetify
      // Requires sass-loader@^9.0.0
      options: {
        implementation: sass,
        sassOptions: { fiber: fibers },
        additionalData: "@import '~/src/styles/variables.scss'",
      }
    }
  ]
}
...
```

**// src/styles/variables.scss**

```
@import "~vuetify/src/styles/settings/_variables.scss";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
$body-font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
$heading-font-family: $body-font-family;
$headings: (
    'h1': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h2': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h3': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h4': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h5': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
    'h6': (
        'font-family': $heading-font-family,
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vuetify v2.4.11

Vue v2.6.12

1. To configure a custom font in Vuetify you need to include this CSS in your App.vue component.

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=New+Tegomin&display=swap');
  $font-family: 'New Tegomin', serif;
  .my-application {
    .headline,
    [class*='display-'],
    [class*='text-'] {
      color: #36405a;
      font-family: $font-family, sans-serif !important;
    }
    font-family: $font-family, sans-serif !important;
  }
</style>
```

2. Put a specific class in your  node, something like that:

`<v-app class="my-application">`

This second point is important because all the font styles from Vuetify have `!important` and if you want to overwrite, you need to put an extra class...

I hope that this tip helps everyone!

Answer (score 1):

How I achieved it: (Vuetify 2+)

1) Into your index.html, import your fonts.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>fonts/<MY_CUSTOM_FONT>/fontface.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Literata:100,300,400,500,700,900">
```

2) Inside `/src`, create a `styles` directory and a file named `variables.scss` inside it

3) In that file, override some variables values:

```
// Globals
$body-font-family: 'MY_CUSTOM_FONT'; // Used on content
$heading-font-family: 'Literata';    // Used on helpers classes
```

Hope it helps someone.

References:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8169
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#example-variable-file

Answer (score 1):

it is a late reply but , You can add in common scss/sass/less file (which is called in App.vue or you main App file) it will implement it all over the application

```
.body,
.v-application{
    font-family: 'Antic', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem in February 2023. This is an answer that works specifically on Vuetify 3 inside Nuxt 3.
Here is a very simple way:

1. Go to get the source of your fonts. eg. Google font.
2. Input those fonts link in your nuxt.config:

```
 head: {
      link: [
        {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          href: 'https://your-font-source.com'
        },
      ]
 },
```

3. Apply the font-family to the `html` selector inside one of the Vue Components as a none scoped style:

```html
<style>
  html {
    font-family: 'Your font name';
  }
</style>
```

If there's no override font specifically set in the components this font will be used throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier and proper way than all of the methods above. Add

```
treeShake: true,
defaultAssets: {
  font: {
    family: 'Poppins'
  }
}
```

to the vuetify object in **nuxt.config.js**. This should properly enable your font family throughout the application.(see [defaultAssets](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#defaultassets) documentation for more details and note that the treeShake option is required)

Comment: Important: This solution requires a nuxt community package "vuetify-module" to work

Answer (score 0):

Extra helpful thing:

- when changing font from Roboto to any other font, by default vuetify will still import the cdn Roboto fonts file (url) in the "head" tag. To avoid that extra thing use the "defaultAssets: false" option under vuetify settings.

**EDITED**
That thing only works within NUXTJS, thanks to @nlavr for pointing it out

Comment: In Vuetify there is no option 'defaultAssets: false', at least at 2.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering the same issue but aren't using Nuxt, and instead are using Vuetify alone, you can try the following steps:

In your vue.config.js file, add the following code:

```
css: {

    loaderOptions: {

      sass: {

        additionalData: `@import "@/assets/main.scss"`

      }

    }

  },
```

In your main.scss file, add the following line:

```
$body-font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif !default;
```

Finally, in your index.html file, include the following link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap">
```

that works for me!

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR:

1. Copy the font file to your project.
2. Register the font with your project so it can be used.
3. Configure Vuetify to use the font as its default.

### Step 1: Copy the font file to your project

I copied the font file to this path:

`/my-app/frontend/src/assets/fonts/<font-name-goes-here>.<file-extension>`

### Step 2: Register the font with your project so it can be used

The second step is to register the font with your Vue app so that you can use it at all.

I added a `@font-face` rule to a `fonts.css` file:

`/my-app/frontend/src/styles/fonts.css`

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '<font-name-goes-here>';
    src: url('../assets/fonts/<font-name-goes-here>.<file-extension>') format('<font-type>');
}
```

---

I then registered the `font.css` file in my `main.ts` file:

`/my-app/frontend/src/main.ts`

```
(...)
// Styles
import '@/styles/fonts.css';
(...)
```

### Step 3: Configure Vuetify to use the font as its default

I set the `$body-font-family` Vuetify variable to be my new font in a `settings.scss` file:

`/my-app/frontend/src/styles/settings.scss`

```
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  (...)
  $body-font-family: '<font-name-goes-here>',
);
```

---

...and I have that `settings.scss` file registered in my `vite.config.js` file:

`/my-app/frontend/vite.config.js`

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    (...)
    vuetify({
      (...)
      styles: {
        configFile: 'src/styles/settings.scss',
      },
    }),
  ],
(...)
```

---

Useful links:

- https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/#basic-usage