# Default font is partially changed in VuetifyJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i am using Vuetify 2.0.14. i have followed this post [Change Default Font in Vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57669275/2723677) and taken the solution from @tzahi-leh. But i see the web page is partially changed with my custom font. I know Vuetify has the default Roboto font and i wanted to be changed as 'Ubunut'. i also download the Ubuntu font family and placed inside the `assets/fonts` folder.

my App.vue `Style Content`

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
$typoOptions: display-4 display-3 display-2 display-1 headline title subtitle-1 subtitle-2 body-1 body-2 caption overline;

%font-choice {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif !important;
}

@mixin md-typography {
  @each $typoOption in $typoOptions {
    .#{$typoOption} {
      @extend %font-choice;
    }
  }
}

.v-application {
  // font-size: 12px;
  @extend %font-choice;
  @include md-typography;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Ubuntu"), local("Ubuntu"),
  url("~@/assets/fonts/Ubuntu-R.ttf") format("ttf");
}
</style>
```

Output page looks like bwlow. The Red highlighted are still showing as Roboto font style, where others are changed to Ubuntu font style.

[image: issue screen]

I noticed that the styles with `display-4 display-3 display-2 display-1 headline title subtitle-1 subtitle-2 body-1 body-2 caption overline` are not behaving for/with custom style fonts.

Any help on how to change completely to my custom font on whole website? please

Answer (score 1):

**Best way**

Define (if you use google fonts)

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Oxygen:300,400,700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Comfortaa&display=swap');

$body-font-family: 'Oxygen';
$title-font: 'Comfortaa';
```

For vuetify 2+

```
.v-application {
   font-family: $body-font-family, sans-serif !important;
    .title { // To pin point specific classes of some components
       font-family: $title-font, sans-serif !important;
    }
 }
```

**Notice the separate declaration of `.title` as those are often given a different font (A display font) same goes for `.heading` and `.subheading`.**

Write this in your app.vue or a separate scss/css file imported directly into app.vue.

For vuetify 1.5.x In your app.vue script add

```
.application {
  font-family: "Font Family Name";
}
.headline,
.title,
.subheading{
     font-family: $body-font-family !important;
}
```

For example, if you are using a google font, your script tag should look like

```
<style lang="scss">
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial");

.application {
  font-family: "Questrial";
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scoped` from `<style lang="scss" scoped>`

Comment: i have removed `scoped` and tried that too. if i remove that, even menu titles are displayed as 'Roboto' font.

Comment: Can you upload the project to Github Repo and send me the link will be happy to look into it.

I was having a same issue following few answers I end up on this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot of time, i found an answer.

First you need import the vuetify sass settings:

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles';
```

and change **$body-font-family** variable to your font-family

```
$body-font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
```

then override the typography settings like in the doc: [Sass Variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables#vue-cli-3-setup)

```
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h1' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h2' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h3' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h4' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h5' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'h6' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'subtitle-1' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'subtitle-2' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'body-1' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'body-2' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
$headings: map-deep-set($headings, 'caption' 'font-family', $body-font-family);
```