# How to use custom font weight in Vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

all. I'm new to Vuetify. Vuetify has its default font-weight for 500 and 700; but I want to use font-weight: 600; So, this means I need to define a custom style in Vuetify. Is there any method I can achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you have to create own global class. You also have to be sure you import a font with `font-weight 600`. See here how to import fonts: [Change default font in vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598884/change-default-font-in-vuetify)

Comment: Thx! That's what I want.