# Using Scss Variable Overrides in Vue 3 with Vuetify 3 Beta Using Vue CLI

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetify-loader, vuetifyjs3

I am working on a project using Vue 3, Vuetify 3.0.0 (beta 0), and the latest Vue-CLI. I am trying to customize the vuetify font, however every method i've found online to override the vue sass variables has not worked.

The first attempt I made was was using the Vuetify documentation on the vuetify website: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/

Using a default project, I added a `styles` directory and `variables.scss` file as directed. Inside the `variables.scss` file I have the following contents:

```
$body-font-family: cursive;
```

Digging through the variables inside the Vuetify lib directory It looks like this variable I needed to override (and while I will be using a custom font, for now cursive should ensure a different enought font to validate it works).

This did not work, I tried changing the directory to `scss` and got the same results (it does not import) see the result image below.
[image]

So my second attempt was following the documentation found ing the `vue.config.js` file where it points to https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader#customising-variables . This led to me changing my `vue.config.js` file to look like:

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const { VuetifyLoaderPlugin } = require("vuetify-loader");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,

  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin({ styles: "expose" })],
  },

  pluginOptions: {
    vuetify: {
      // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader
    },
  },
});
```

with a main.scss file added to the plugins dir with the following contents:

```
// main.scss
$font: cursive !important;

@use 'vuetify/styles' with (
  $color-pack: false,
  $utilities: false,
  $body-font-family: $font
);
```

This basically removed all formating from the page but did not change the text to a cursive font (see image below)
[image]

At this point I have been searching online and been unable to find anything that has worked:

- Initial research led me [Change default font in vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598884/change-default-font-in-vuetify) this is where I got my first two approaches, I did not have luck with the sass loaders either.
- In the git repo https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/221 seems to pose a similar question but lead to no results
- [How to override vuetify 3 components sass variable with vue 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71234770/how-to-override-vuetify-3-components-sass-variable-with-vue-3) poses a similar question but lacked the depth

Here is a git repo with my current code: https://github.com/dragonman117/Vuetify-Theme-Test

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just fought with this for a solid 2 hours and FINALLY figured it out. Stumbled upon your question and figured I'd throw you a bone, even if it is 3 months later.

The problem currently is that the [Vuetify 3 docs for this](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/) are not up to date. I'm going to try my hand at updating the docs in a PR after this. The key missing piece is that vuetify-loader was used for Vuetify 2, but Vuetify 3 is using the new [wepback-plugin-vuetify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-plugin-vuetify). I figured that out when I stumbled upon [vuetify-loader's "next" branch (see the README)](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next).

Anyway, here's all you need for when you're using a Vue CLI installation.

*vuetify.ts*

```
import @/styles/variables.scss;
// the rest of your vuetify.ts file...
```

*variables.scss*

```
@use "vuetify/styles" with (
  $body-font-family: "Comic Sans"
);
```

Edit: Also, I just started having issues with including commas in my font family in that list after the "with," so I ended up doing the following. This may not be the best SASSy solution for this, but idk their syntax well enough to come up with something else atm:

*variables.scss*

```
$body-font-family: Inter, sans-serif;

@use "vuetify/styles" with (
  $body-font-family: $body-font-family
);
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: It's been one year and this is still the answer. It's pretty incredible that Vue 3's docs are still outdated.

Comment: Oh good, another reason for me to hate it . (Tbf, these were about Veutify’s docs. Still mad about it tho.)

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to override default typography settings:

```
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
  $heading-font-family: Comic Sans,
  $body-font-family: Comic Sans,
  $typography: (
    'h1': (
      'size': 2rem,
      'weight': 500,
      'line-height': 2.2rem,
      'letter-spacing': 0,
      'font-family': Comic Sans,
      'text-transform': none
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

Update (as 2023-04) (using Nuxt 3.2.0 + Vuetify 3.1.4)

There's no need to import the variables file. I just set the configFile in the vite plugin to point to the variables path file.

```js
  // nuxt.config.ts
  modules: [
    async (options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook("vite:extendConfig", (config) =>
        // @ts-ignore
        config.plugins.push(
          vuetify({
            styles: { configFile: "assets/scss/variables.scss" },
          })
        )
      );
    },
  ],
```

Credits to: https://github.com/BayBreezy/vuetify3-nuxt3-sass-customized